# RewriteRule not working strangly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Rules are actually simple.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^path2/myoldurl\.php$ /mynewurl? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^path2/myoldur\.php$ /mynewurl? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

The first rules has been there for ages and it is working. But when I tried to add the second one which removed one letter from the first one, is not working at all. When I change the RewriteRule with Redirect or RedirectMatch, it is working.

Bu I cannot use RedirectMatch and Redirect because I have to clear out query string also.

Is there any idea why it is not working? I already restarted the apache also. Can it be these RewriteRule cache in some where?

### EDIT

I just realized that the old rules is still working even after I removed both rules. But I'm sure .htaccess is working since it redirect the new url when I add Redirect 301 or RedirectMatch in this file.  Please help!!!!

### EDIT 2

One more thing I realized is that, once I added a new Redirect script it is working. And it is still working EVEN AFTER I REMOVED IT BACK :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make that letter `l` optional. So it will match either one of them and you have one rewriterule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^path2/myoldurl?\.php$ /mynewurl? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Clear your browser cache before trying new rules.

Comment: I think your code should be the problem solver. But it is not working for me. And I also realize that, the old rule still working even after I removed both rules.  But I'm sure .htaccess is working because it is taking effect when I add redirect or redirectMatch. Any Idea?

Comment: Did you fully clear your cache? Sounds like a caching problem. Try a different browser. Also make sure you don't have this somewhere else like in the apache config.

Comment: Yes, I already check in the other browsers and chrome incognito mode. No different.   

One more thing I realized is that, once I added a new Redirect script it is working. And it is still working EVEN AFTER I REMOVED IT BACK :(

I head almost blown up. Please help!!

Comment: I don't know if you have some other caching issue on the server or something else is going on. There's no way to tell what's going without looking at it. check your error logs. Also do restart of apache after each change and see what happens.

Comment: Another thing, I've seen that was causing an issue was the FTP client or editor not saving it to the server properly. Check those things

Comment: there is nth inside error log and I restarted apache many times. Also the file is updated since everytime I add new changes, It is effected. It just not working new RewriteRules. !_!

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` at the top of the .htaccess?

Comment: Yes I have this RewriteEngine on at the top of my rules.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Post your entire .htaccess. Maybe something else is an issue.

Comment: can I just pm you? I don't want to post all the urls in here.